# How to have a table scroll only within a custom control on page? CSS help needed

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, gridview

I have a custom control(ascx) that has some text plus a gridview.  Here is what I'm trying to do.  I want an table(with some information) within a div tag to scroll beside the gridview within the custom control. I don't what the table to scroll down the whole page. I don't have paging on the gridview because the user needs to see everything within one browser window.

I tried playing around with position value of fixed, absolute and relative.  I placed the gridview within a div tag that had a value of position:relative and another div tag embedded within the main div tag with a value of position:fixed and left:70%.  I get a partial result that I'm trying to achieve. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you have a div with a specific height and then use overflow:auto or scroll ?

Comment: could you draw what you want to achieve or post a fiddle. The description of your problem isn't tottaly clear for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar requirement in my project and i achieved it by having a div tag with specific with then set overflow to auto

```
<div id ="mydiv" style ="width: 1000px;overflow:auto"/>
```

you may set the height to a specific width.